# Convert ObjectResult<string> to ObjectModel.Collection<string>

Tags: c#

One of the data member in my data contract is of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>`.
I am getting a result of type `ObjectResult<string>` after executing a function import . How to convert `objectresult<string>` to `ObjectModel.Collection<string>`. Is there any direct cast exists?

Comment: Is ObjectResult an IEnumerable?

Comment: yes it is an IEnumerable   public sealed class ObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObjectModel.Collection<string> col = new ObjectModel.Collection<string>(objectResult.ToList());
```

Comment: Hi Haris\,that works. Hope that is the right way to do it. thank u.